# gpg encryption fails : File open error

Tags: c#, encryption, gnupg

I am trying to encrypt using gpg but i get this error even though i have given the path explicitly.. can some one help me?
I am using Starksoft.Cryptography.OpenPGP.
I have installed the gpg4win-light-2.1.0.exe to obtain the gpg.exe file..

is there something i am missing?

Error:GPG executable not found. @C:\Program Files\GNU\GnuPG\gpg.exe\gpg2.exe.

```
        GnuPG gpg = new GnuPG();
        gpg.BinaryPath = "@C:\\Program Files\\GNU\\GnuPG\\gpg.exe";
        gpg.Recipient = "myfriend@domain.com";
        FileStream sourceFile = new FileStream(sourcePath, FileMode.Open);
        FileStream outputFile = new FileStream(Destinationpath, FileMode.Create);
        gpg.Encrypt(sourceFile,outputFile);
        sourceFile.Close();
        outputFile.Close();
```

I even have a licence for openBlackboxPGP.. can i encrypt using gpg using that??

Please help me if i am missing something!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: (Changed from a comment to an answer, see below.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to say

```
gpg.BinaryPath = @"C:\Program Files\GNU\GnuPG\gpg.exe";
```

(note the placement of the `@`), or

```
gpg.BinaryPath = "C:\\Program Files\\GNU\\GnuPG\\gpg.exe";
```

although you are probably better off using the more readable form

```
gpg.BinaryPath = "C:/Program Files/GNU/GnuPG/gpg.exe";
```

Comment: nothing changes if i do that too it still says cant find gpg2.exe :( can u please help me?

Comment: Perhaps you need to leave off the filename part, and only use `"C:/Program Files/GNU/GnuPG"`?

Comment: i get this error now gpgwrap: executing `C:\gpg2.exe' failed: No such file or directory:(:(